# Parse Android SDK binding additions, how to convert interfaces to events

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm trying to convert the usage of interfaces from Parse's Android SDK to C# events by following this: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/java_integration_overview/binding_a_java_library_(.jar)/#Normalizing_the_API or most of it. The specific parts I need to convert are interfaces like these:

https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/SendCallback.html

Notice how the interface has only one method (Done(ParseException e)). Well when I try to create a helper class like the tutorial says I'm presented with the need to implement not just that method but another method from some random obscure ParseCallback1 interface.

The generated interface is as follows:

```
// Metadata.xml XPath interface reference: path="/api/package[@name='com.parse']/interface[@name='SendCallback']"
[Register ("com/parse/SendCallback", "", "Com.Parse.ISendCallbackInvoker")]
public partial interface ISendCallback : global::Com.Parse.IParseCallback1 {

        // Metadata.xml XPath method reference:     path="/api/package[@name='com.parse']/interface[@name='SendCallback']/method[@name='done' and count(parameter)=1 and parameter[1][@type='com.parse.ParseException']]"
        [Register ("done", "(Lcom/parse/ParseException;)V", "GetDone_Lcom_parse_ParseException_Handler:Com.Parse.ISendCallbackInvoker, ParseBindings")]
        void Done (global::Com.Parse.ParseException 

}
```

It does extend from ParseCallback1 but why is it that in Java I just have to implement one method and here those two?

On top of that the interface is not public on the jars so when I compile the project that uses this helper class:

```
internal partial class SendCallbackEventMapper : Java.Lang.Object,
Com.Parse.ISendCallback
{

    public void Done(Com.Parse.ParseException e) {
    }

    public void Done(Java.Lang.Object o) {
    }
}
```

I get the errors on the attached file.

```
Error:  error: ParseCallback1 is not public in com.parse; cannot be accessed from outside package
        com.parse.ParseCallback1
 (ParsePush)

Error:  error: name clash: done(Throwable) in SendCallbackEventMapper and done(T) in ParseCallback1 have the same erasure, yet neither overrides the other
    public void done (java.lang.Throwable p0)
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Throwable declared in interface ParseCallback1
 (ParsePush)
```

What are my options here? I really need to implement these methods. I can't even use the provided interfaces such as SendCallback with these errors so I can't really use ANY of the InBackground methods from the Parse SDK.

Answer (score 0):

In order to fox this IParseCallback1 issues just add this lines to the /Transforms/Metadata.xml file:

```
<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.parse']/interface[@name='ParseCallback1']" name="visibility">public</attr>
<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.parse']/interface[@name='ParseCallback2']" name="visibility">public</attr>
```